# Load an XML color scheme file in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm tying to load an XML color scheme file into PowerPoint.  I was able to successfully write a routine to save the XML color scheme.

I found that in MS Word VBA this can be done by:

```
ActiveDocument.Documenttheme.ThemeColorScheme.Load "file path & name*"
```

But I can't figure out how to load it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you're unsure how things are organized in PPT VBA, best bet is to go to the VBA Object Browser, and search on the terms you're looking for.  For example `ThemeColorScheme` is a member of items such as `Slide` and `SlideRange` and also has `Load` and `Save` methods

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you,  You pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load (tPath & fName)
```

Thanks @tedwilliams